# Problema com quebra de linha e substr no php

Tags: php

Fiz um retângulo que contem o título do artigo, esse título é limitado usando o **substr** do php, mas quando uma palavra é grande ele quebra a linha continuando o texto em baixo, porém o número de caracteres continua o mesmo, só que o texto acaba ficando maior que retângulo por causa da quebra de linha. Alguém poderia me ajudar como solução, não quero que aumente o retângulo.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se com essa função ajudaria em algo:

```
 function limit_chars($string,$caracteres = 100)
{
     $string = strip_tags($string);
    if (strlen($string) > $caracteres) {
        while (substr($string,$caracteres,1) <> ' ' && ($caracteres < strlen($string))){
            $caracteres++;
        };
    };
    if (strlen(substr($string,0,$caracteres)) < $caracteres){
        return substr($string,0,$caracteres);
    }else{
        return substr($string,0,$caracteres)."...";
    }

}
```

Assim com essa função vai ser possível você limitar a quantidade de caracteres e ainda terá "..." ao final.
Espero ter ajudado :D

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você precisa é resolvido facilmente com [css](/questions/tagged/css)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div.test {
    white-space:nowrap; 
    width:12em; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test" style="text-overflow:ellipsis;">Este é apenas um texto longo para exemplificar o funcionamento</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

com isso o resultado será `Este é apenas um texto lon...`

Você pode ver o exemplo funcionando [**aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zfyb/) e ver todas as definições de uso do `text-overflow` [**aqui**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/text-overflow).

Comment: Funciona, porém preciso de algo que funcione no ie7.

Comment: Para isso eu recomendo um pluguin [tag:jquery] http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/